# Advice on a library to extract information on Word Documents Azure

Tags: ms-word, text-extraction

How do I read line for line or extract the text line by line in a Microsoft Word document ith openXML. Reading the file from azure blob storage and working with it in memory.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: FYI tool/product/service recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have now made it very specific